# Targeting classes in events

Tags: aframe

Is it possible to target classes in events instead of unique ids? For example:

```
<a-event name="click" target=".allmyvideos" radius="5000"></a-event>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-event-set-component/ which replaces `<a-event>`.

Right now, the event-set component does support classes, but I need add support for `querySelectorAll`. You can file an issue at https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-event-set-component.